# How do I get POST data with node.js?

Tags: node.js, twilio

How do I get the caller ID from twilio? I've tried many different ways to get the POST data but it isn't working.

```
var twilio = require('./node_modules/twilio/index'),
        http = require('http'),
        express = require('express');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
/*
var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.post('/call',function (req, res) {
*/
        var name, from;
//      if (req.method=='POST')
//              req.on('From', function (data) {from = data;});
        try {
                from = req.param('From');
                // from = req.body.from;
        }
        catch (err)
        {
        console.log("No Caller ID");
        }
        console.log("Number: " + from);
//Some code goes here..
res.end(resp.toString());
}).listen(8080);
```

It's throwing me the error every single time at the try catch statement (always null).

*I'm trying to get the caller ID of an incoming text message.*

Things in comments are the different approaches I tried.

The thrown error is:

> Error TypeError: Object #IncomingMessage> has no method 'param'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that this will do the trick:

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var processRequest = function(req, callback) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        callback(qs.parse(body));
    });
}

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    processRequest(req, function(data) {
        // data
    }); 
}).listen(9000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: To get a parameter like 'From', would I do data.param('From')?

Comment: It should be `data.From`.

Comment: What about binary file uploads to a server?